# ReactNative: I want to remove objects from array in a list

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Here is my code for remove items**

```
const list = await AsyncStorage.getItem("ParcelList");

var res = JSON.parse(list);

//it contains array of multiple stored values [{value:{},value:{},value:{},value:{},]

var select = this.state.selectedData;

//this is the selected items I want to delete [{value:{},value:{}}]

 const postsItems = res.filter(item => !select.includes(item));

await AsyncStorage.setItem('ParcelList',JSON.stringify(postsItems));

var resl = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ParcelList',);
```

please help me what is wrong with this and provide me a solution for multiple objects remove from array

Comment: Can you please share structure of `value:{ ??? }` object. Your approach of using `filter` is just fine but the way you are comparing to filter object is not correct. You need to compare the object on their property values.

Comment: [ { value: 
     { Description: 'Test',
       Length: '10',
       Height: '23',
       Weight: '20',
       VolumeWeight: 0.92,
       ActualWeight: '23' }]

Comment: how to compare the multiple objects with original data objects? can you give me a sample for it?

Comment: Which property you want to compare against each object like `Description`, `VolumeWeight` etc?

Comment: any one of the property or VolumeWeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as `.filter` predicate to test objects on multiple properties, like

```js
var res = [{description: 'ab', VolumeWeight: 0.92}, {description: 'cb', VolumeWeight: 0.90}, {description: 'ab', VolumeWeight: 0.89}]

var selected = [{description: 'ab', VolumeWeight: 0.92}]


var result = res.filter(item => !selected.some(itemToRemove => item.VolumeWeight === itemToRemove.VolumeWeight && item.description === itemToRemove.description));

console.log(result);
```

In the above example, `{description: 'ab', VolumeWeight: 0.92}` will be filtered from `res` array based on `description` and `VolumeWeight` property value. You can put any number of properties you like in `.some` method to match your requirement.

Hope this will help!

Comment: using `some` with `filter` filter will be slow

Comment: Any better alternative to remove multiple elements based on multiple properties? @JunedLanja